# bash script error when running executing openvpn service

Tags: bash-scripting

I am trying to develop a bash script that calls a service from within:

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=dev0
mycommand="sudo openvpn --config '/etc/openvpn/optionFile.ovpn'"

$mycommand
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

```
Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: '/etc/openvpn/optionFile.ovpn'
```

The permissions to the file are also set correctly and I am executing the file as root

Comment: Have you tried looking for the error? Seems like stuff from this link https://forums.openvpn.net/topic8014.html could help you out a bit. Also if you could post the Linux Distro in the question it could be helpful.

Comment: thanks a lot I was able to find out that issue on the link you provided, had to remove off the single quotes in the path to the ovpn file. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: one other thing If you could help out, inside the "optionFile.ovpn" there are some other files included. Do you know how I can set the basepath so that "optionFile.ovpn" can resolve the correct path to load files from the bash script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since That fixed it for you im going to put it as the answer for Future use.

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=dev0
mycommand="sudo openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/optionFile.ovpn"

$mycommand
```

Remove the Single Quotes and the command will work.